# Файл .py в .exe

Tags: python, exe

Я знаю, что существует pyinstaller. Проблема в том, что мне нужно создать *программу*-упаковщик. То есть при запуске программы выполнялось бы всё то, что делал pyinstaller.

P.S. pyinstaller не может работать как библиотека
P.P.S. программа-упаковщик должна работать на *всех* компьютерах, независимо от того установлен python или нет

Comment: сделать ехе и патом зипнутый ехе,который везде установится/запустится, не вариант ? зачем вам '''при запуске программы выполнялось бы всё то, что делал pyinstaller''' ?

Comment: @Интик я хочу сделать так, чтобы в мою другую программу установщик записал IP и имя компьюетера (запихнуть прямо в код). Для того чтобы пиратство хоть немного предотвратить